# When do you use a block as an object to be passed around?

Tags: ruby, block

Most of the examples I see are trivial, and I'm not sure what this adds to the language. I get why you would use blocks in Objective-C for handling callbacks or in Javascript with closures used as callbacks for timers, but I'm not sure what I'd be using blocks for in Ruby. Is it something that could be used instead of a function with something like `inject`?

Comment: really, downvoting for no reason?

Comment: I didn't down-vote, but some *Ruby-specific* exploration should have occurred first. There are numerous examples online of "blocks in ruby" and much discussion over the "blocks vs Proc/lambda" ..

Comment: While relatively new to ruby, I've used blocks a lot; in fact have written prob 10 tonight (Xmas eve no less). Most of the examples I see are trivial whether in books or in source code. Honestly, I'm looking for something that couldn't be done another way. There's some inject stuff (again mentioned in op) possibly.

Comment: Your question is getting downvoted because you didn't do enough research before asking. Blocks are core to Ruby, and are anything but trivial. Look through Ruby's documentation, and books on Ruby, and you'll see many practical examples: `IO.open`, `OpenURI#open`, `Net::HTTP`, `Enumerable#each` and `Enumerable#map` all take blocks and I use them multiple times daily.

Comment: that's not the question. The question is what is an exemplary non-trivial example of using blocks in Ruby that couldn't just as easily be achieved using a function and I provide the example of callbacks in client side language.

Comment: According to the question summary, the question is "Is it something that could be used instead of a function with something like inject?"  If the question has changed, please change the question, rather than changing it *only* in the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ruby uses blocks all over, it's one of the most ubiquitous features of the language. It is basically an optimised case of a function-as-a-value. A real function object, like in JavaScript is in Ruby an instance of a `Proc` class. A block is *not* an object, and thus avoids some of the overheads that objecthood incurs. The reasoning is, in almost all cases where you want to pass a function as an argument, you'll only be passing one, and you'll want to define it right there on the spot, so why not optimise, and make things a bit syntactically nicer?

This is a block:

```
[1, 2, 3].each do |i|
  puts i
end
```

This is a function:

```
func = Proc.new do |i|
  puts i
end
[1, 2, 3].hypothetical_each(func)
```

You can see that even defining a functional value involves a block (as a parameter to `Proc` constructor).

You normally use a block in `inject`, not a function. You use it in pretty much every loop structure in Ruby (`while` is very uncommonly used).

You also use blocks to construct domain-specific languages like Sinatra:

```
get 'index.html' do
  "Hello World"
end
```

or Rspec:

```
describe "addition" do
  it "should add two numbers together" do
    (1+2).should equal(3)
  end
end
```

Learn blocks well, because you can't read, nor write Ruby well without them.

Comment: thx for response but the question isn't what is a block; it's what a really good example of using a block that couldn't be achieved via a standard function.

Comment: honestly, a run time should be able to do those optimizations on the fly.

Comment: And I answered: blocks are syntactic sugar for argument functions, minus object overhead. Aside from aesthetics and speed, there is nothing you can do with blocks that you can't do with `Proc` objects.

Comment: As for `inject` and other functions that normally don't have a function argument but instead require a block, you can always pass a function as if it was a block using the `&` operator.

Answer (score 0):

The secret to blocks in ruby is held in the nature of ruby's design.

Ruby was designed with an object modal where method calls are sent as 'messages' to the object and return values are responses. In ruby (unlike python and some other languages), functions and methods are NOT object themselves.
Blocks are ruby's way of allowing function-like messages in this modal and are key to how ruby handles iteration in general.

Someone please correct me if I'm wrong but I believe it is in fact impossible to do any iteration in ruby without creating a block or using a while statement
and in fact the `for i in object` notation is just syntax shorthand for access to the object `each` method.

ie.

```
for i in 1..5
  #do stuff with i
end
```

Is executed exactly the same as:

```
1..5.each do |i|
  #do stuff with i
end
```

By the ruby VM where the Range object `1..5` (which includes the ruby standart lib Enumerable module) yields it's elements to the passed block

Under the hood this operation looks something like this (note this is a simplified version that fails to take into account the ... exclusive and .. inclusive version of range)

```
class Range

  def init(start, end)
    @start = start
    @end = end
  end

  def each
    i = @start
    while i < @end
      yield i
      i += 1
    end
  end

end
```

So when that for loop is called it creates a range object `obj = Range.new(1,5)` then sends a message to the object `obj.send(:each, &block)` and inside the each method is use a while loop and yields to the block

**TL;DR**

Ruby uses block internally as they are critical to it's very design, without them the language itself would not work with it's `message => object => response` modal.

So you should not ask: "Why should I use blocks?" Because you can't write a ruby program without them.

Instead you should ask: "How is a block in ruby different than a block in Objective-C and Javascript?" Because they ARE a different.

I cant speak for Objective-C but in JavaScript a block is very much an object. It's a container for code that other objects can pick up and use to do whatever it needs to, the block doesnt even have to relate to the object using it.

In ruby a block is more like a set of instruction an object receives in the mail that it uses on itself (which it then passes to the mail man the next time he comes around)